# Getting bookcover dimensions right

Tags: xetex, dimensions, bookcover

I have to follow this template:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[spinewidth=11mm,coverwidth=180mm,coverheight=276mm,flapwidth=0mm,dvipsnames,svgnames,marklength=0mm]{bookcover}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

However, this gives me a document with dimensions of 381x286.000472mm ... which is much too large. How do I fix this?

Comment: It appears that bookcover is (by default) adding 5mm bleed on all four sides. This is quite realistic for print technology. Looking at the 15mm edge specs on your diagram, I believe that refers to the "dead zone" which must exclude text (although it does include image). It is not the same as the bleed area.

Comment: You might want to talk to a printer about what size sheets they use for covers.  It will be larger than the printed area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case coverwidth=155+10=165mm and coverheight=246mm. You can define new bookcover parts, namely:

> back left, back right, front left, front right

Try the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass[coverwidth=165mm,coverheight=246mm,spinewidth=11mm]{bookcover}
\newbookcoverpart{back left}{\setpartposx{15mm}\setpartposy{15mm}\setpartwidth{155mm}\setpartheight{246mm}}
\newbookcoverpart{back right}{\setpartposx{170mm}\setpartposy{15mm}\setpartwidth{10mm}\setpartheight{246mm}}
\newbookcoverpart{front left}{\setpartposx{191mm}\setpartposy{15mm}\setpartwidth{10mm}\setpartheight{246mm}}
\newbookcoverpart{front right}{\setpartposx{201mm}\setpartposy{15mm}\setpartwidth{155mm}\setpartheight{246mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{back left}{color=blue}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{back right}{color=blue!50}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{spine}{color=yellow}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front left}{color=red!50}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front right}{color=red}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{spine}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\bfseries\Large Book title}}
\bookcovercomponent{normal}{front right}{
\vspace{5cm}
\begin{center}
\bfseries\huge Book title
\end{center}}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```